# Skype API program run error

Tags: c#

I'm trying to show online/offline contacts from Skype, but I get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   WindowsFormsApplication2.exe
>
> Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component
>   with CLSID {830690FC-BF2F-47A6-AC2D-330BCB402664} failed due to the
>   following error: 80040154.

Debugger says that an error is in: `Skype skype = new Skype();`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SKYPE4COMLib;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        Skype skype = new Skype();


        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(loadContacts));
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
            thread.Name = "Load Skype Contacts";
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        List<string> contacts = new List<string>();

        public void loadContacts() 
        {
            contacts.Clear();
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                foreach(User user in skype.Friends)
                {
                    contacts.Add(user.Handle);
                }
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                foreach (User user in skype.Friends)
                {
                    if (user.OnlineStatus == TOnlineStatus.olsOnline | user.OnlineStatus == TOnlineStatus.olsNotAvailable | user.OnlineStatus == TOnlineStatus.olsDoNotDisturb | user.OnlineStatus == TOnlineStatus.olsAway)
                    {
                        contacts.Add(user.Handle);
                    }
                }
            }
            MethodInvoker lvUpdate = delegate
            {
                listView1.Items.Clear();
                foreach (var user in contacts)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(user);
                }
                listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
                if (radioButton1.Checked)
                {
                    radioButton1.Text = String.Format("Online ({0})", listView1.Items.Count);
                }
                else if (radioButton2.Checked)
                {
                    radioButton2.Text = String.Format("All contacts ({0})", listView1.Items.Count);
                }
            };
            Invoke(lvUpdate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a attached your Skype object to Skype ( skype.Attach(protocal, wait) )?

Comment: Yes, i have. Looks like the problem is with .dll; But i can't get - why? I added it from VS2013, it is not downloaded from other sources.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

`Build -> Configuration Manager -> Acitve solution platform -> New -> x86` (instead of x64)
This helped.